# Why are pthreads executing sequentially in c

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm creating 10 pthreads in c and it seems that they are running sequentially for some reason.  I've assigned an id to  each thread and I'm writing the id to the array 10 times for each thread. Once the 10 threads are done writing, I parse the array. When going through the array, the id for each thread appears consecutively. There are 100 ids being written to the array and they're all being written consecutively. What I'm expecting is race conditions to occur so that some id's are overwritten. I'm also not expecting all the ids to appear consecutively in the array.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//Count variabes and flags
int noItemsToProduce = 10; //Number of items produced by a single thread.
int totalItemsToProduce = 100; //Number of items produced by 10 threads.
int noItemsConsumed = 0; //Number of items removed by consumer.
int done = 0; //Flag used to know when to terminate.
int queueEmpty = 0;
void *res; //Stores the result from the thread.

//Queue Variables
int *queueArray;
int front = 0;
int back = -1;

void enqueue(int item)
{
    if(back < totalItemsToProduce-1)
    {
        queueArray[++back] = item;
    }
}

void dequeue()
{
    if(front<=back)
    {
        front++;
    }
    else
    {
        queueEmpty = 1;
        front=0;
        back=-1;
    }
}

static void *producer(void *arg)
{
    int i;
    int id = strtol(arg,NULL,0);
    for(i=0;i<noItemsToProduce;i++)
    {
        enqueue(id);
    }
}

static void *consumer(void *arg)
{
    while(!done || !queueEmpty)
    {
        printf("Dequeuing item with id = %d at pos = %d.\n",queueArray[front],front);
        dequeue();
        noItemsConsumed++;
    }
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    //The user needs to specify the number of ints each of the 10
    //producers will produce.
    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s #-items-for-each-producer\n",argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        noItemsToProduce = strtol(argv[1],NULL,0);
        totalItemsToProduce = 10*noItemsToProduce;
        queueArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*totalItemsToProduce);
    }

    //Declarations.
    queueArray = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(10*noItemsToProduce));
    pthread_t p1;
    pthread_t p2;
    pthread_t p3;
    pthread_t p4;
    pthread_t p5;
    pthread_t p6;
    pthread_t p7;
    pthread_t p8;
    pthread_t p9;
    pthread_t p10;
    pthread_t c;

    //Start producer and consumer threads.
    pthread_create(&p1,NULL,producer,"1");
    pthread_create(&p2,NULL,producer,"2");
    pthread_create(&p3,NULL,producer,"3");
    pthread_create(&p4,NULL,producer,"4");
    pthread_create(&p5,NULL,producer,"5");
    pthread_create(&p6,NULL,producer,"6");
    pthread_create(&p7,NULL,producer,"7");
    pthread_create(&p8,NULL,producer,"8");
    pthread_create(&p9,NULL,producer,"9");
    pthread_create(&p10,NULL,producer,"10");

    //Wait until all of the producers finish producing.
    pthread_join(p1,&res);
    pthread_join(p2,&res); 
    pthread_join(p3,&res); 
    pthread_join(p4,&res); 
    pthread_join(p5,&res); 
    pthread_join(p6,&res); 
    pthread_join(p7,&res); 
    pthread_join(p8,&res); 
    pthread_join(p9,&res); 
    pthread_join(p10,&res); 

    //We're done producing so let the consumer know.
    done = 1;
    pthread_create(&c, NULL, consumer, queueArray);
    pthread_join(c,&res);   
    printf("Total items produced = %d.\n",10*noItemsToProduce);
    printf("Total items consumed = %d.\n",noItemsConsumed-1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrates the issue

Comment: There's no issue. You have an expectation, but nothing in your code *enforces* your expectation. So your expectation is something that *might* happen but isn't *required* to happen. It doesn't happen. No issue.

Comment: Ever heard of things called 'arrays'?  They'd reduce the amount of code in your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have a race condition. What you're seeing in an artefact of your OS's pthreads implementation. If you make each thread do more work (ideally, a lot more work), you'll likely see that artefact disappear.

Comment: Even when I attempt to write the ID of a single thread 1000 times it still writes the ids consecutively in the array.

Comment: @user600194: That's still not a lot of work. In any case, it would help if your question included a complete, runnable example.

Comment: 1000 iterations of writing to an array, with three instructions per iteration, three issue super scalar processor @2GHz -> 0.5 microseconds. Try to make the time taken at least some hundreds of milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

`pthreads` makes zero guarantees about how your threads are scheduled. If they don't do a lot of work, the OS might well schedule each thread serially and let them complete.

If you really want to have them race, make them do some busy work like `for(i=0; i<100000000; i++) write_to_array;`. Of course, even this doesn't guarantee that they will actually race, but it does improve your odds with most schedulers.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask four archers to each get their bow and arrows, go to the field, line up on a target, and fire, you might have two arrows in the air at the same time, but it's not very likely. Most of the time is spent creating and tearing down threads. The probability that two will happen to be accessing the array at the same time is near zero.

Answer (score 0):

> What's the issue?

The "issue" is this:

> I'm also not expecting all the ids to appear consecutively in the array.

I. e. you have expectarions and/or make assumptions about an implementation detail.